# Find the previous year from current date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need in javascript to pass the query in mongodb for record deletion

My date in the db is in this format: "12 Feb 2019 06:45:34 GMT" and I have to get the dates 1 year before for record deletion. How i can do it.

```js
var d = new Date();
var gmt = d.toUTCString();
var s = gmt.slice(5);
var ne = s.setFullYear(s.getFullYear() - 1);

console.log(ne)
```

Comment: As you can see from the snippet I made, s is not a date

Answer (score 1):

You can simply parse it using `new Date("12 Feb 2019 06:45:34 GMT")` and then use the `setFullYear` like you did.

```js
var strDate = "12 Feb 2019 06:45:34 GMT"
var d = new Date(strDate);
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() - 1);
console.log(d.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateString = "12 Feb 2019 06:45:34 GMT";
var d = new Date(dateString);

var s = new Date(d);
s.setFullYear(s.getFullYear() - 1);

console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create some data set**

```
> var dateString = "12 Feb 2019 06:45:34 GMT";
> var dateObject = new Date(dateString);

> db.datetest1.insert({createdDateTime: dateObject})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
// One more record
> db.datetest1.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5def0a895645c25f96ce22ba"), "createdDateTime" : ISODate("2019-02-12T06:45:34Z") }
> var dateString = "12 Feb 2017 06:45:34 GMT";
> var dateObject = new Date(dateString);
> db.datetest1.insert({createdDateTime: dateObject})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

**Find the inserted data into MongoDB collection**

```
> db.datetest1.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5def0a895645c25f96ce22ba"), "createdDateTime" : ISODate("2019-02-12T06:45:34Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5def0abc5645c25f96ce22bb"), "createdDateTime" : ISODate("2017-02-12T06:45:34Z") }
```

**Now Wanted to delete one year older data from collection**

```
> var currentDate = new Date() // current date
> currentDate.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear() -1) // subtract one year
1544410990689
> currentDate
ISODate("2018-12-10T03:03:10.689Z")
// Remove with $multi : true for more than one records
> db.datetest1.remove({createdDateTime: {$lte: currentDate}}, {$multi:true})
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })
// Left data in the collection
> db.datetest1.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5def0a895645c25f96ce22ba"), "createdDateTime" : ISODate("2019-02-12T06:45:34Z") }
>
```

So, answer to your question is that just **create current date object** and subtract one year as `currentDate.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear() -1)` and then pass that value into the `MongoDB remove` query as the above.